# Tricky Recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to solve this little exercise, but not sure how to...

I need to write a function in python, a recursive function, that gets a natural number n as input, and returns a list with n elements, in which each element i is equal to the power of two of i (e.g., [1,4,9,16,...])

My idea was to set the stopping rule to be if n==1 return 1, but I am not sure how to do the second part, which I know should involve f(n-1), but I can't figure out of to do it with the list being there.

Thank you !

Comment: `def powerOfTwo(n, list):if (n == 0) return; list.append(n*n);powerOfTwo(n-1, list)` What's that you are unsure of ? You need immutable list or reverse list or sorted list etc? What's tricky here?

Comment: @SMA, your solution doesn't work.  Ignoring the one-liner issues that keep it from running, you're missing a colon in your `if` statement.  Even if you fix that, it comes out backwards.  Trickier than it looks?

Comment: @cdlane no.. that was just a hint and i did mentioned OP's requirement and i want OP to deal with those stuff and that's the reason its comment and not answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list = []
def recursion(n):
    if n>=1:
        list.insert(0,n**2) //insert in the front of list
        return recursion(n-1)
    else:
        return list
```

For example for n=5

1st - [25]

2nd - [16,25]

3rd - [9,16,25]

4th - [4,9,16,25]

5th - [1,4,9,16,25]

if you prefer, you can pass the list in the parameters, so in that case, the code is:

```
def recursion(n,list):
    if n>=1:
        list.insert(0,n**2) //insert in the front of list
        return recursion(n-1,list)
    else:
        return list
```

PS: i didn't tested it, but i think it will work fine

Comment: Would have been better if you tested it. You need to `return recursion(n-1)` and you have some syntax errors

Comment: Still doesn't work as `//` isn't a Python comment character.  Also, the global `list` should be called something else as `list` is a Python built-in and you've redefined it.  Finally, the use of a global at all is a bad design -- if we call `recursion(5)` twice, the second time we get back `[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]`

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
def recur(a):
    if a<2:
        return [a]
    else:
        return recur(a-1)+[(a)**2]
```

Comment: +1 as one down vote was neither explained nor likely deserved -- it looks like some data scientist downvoted *everyone* after deleting their own flawed answer.